# What is the reason behind methods with return values and methods with void?

Tags: c#, programming-languages, methods

I want to uderstand why there is a method in C# that could reurn a value, for example:

```
public int Accelerate()
{
   Speed++;
   return Speed;
}
```

and a method that does not reurn a value (void)?

What is the difference in the following example of the above one:

```
public void Accelerate()
{
  Speed++;
  Console.WriteLine(Speed);
}
```

I see that last one will save us a time rather than defining a variable to hold this field in when creating a new object! I'm beginner, so could anyone explain?

Comment: Have you studied encapsulation?  That can also be a factor of whether a method has a return value or not.

Comment: It depends upon whether you want to use return value in the calling function or not.

Comment: A method is useful either because it *produces a side effect* or because it *computes a value*. Get in the habit of making every method you write do one or the other but *not both* if possible. Methods that produce side effects should be void; methods that compute values should return the value.

Comment: Sometimes, when you press a button, something is given to you (e.g. a can of soda, from a soda machine). Sometimes, when you press a button, something happens but nothing is given to you directly (e.g. the toilet flushes). I don't see what the root cause of your confusion is that thing _sometimes yield a result and at other times they don't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second one only works within a console based app. It assumes you want to print the speed in a console screen.

The first one will work on a console, or as part os a web app, or as part of a GUI based desktop app, or mobile app.

The first one is therefore more useful as part of a modular system.

The second one is doing a calculation and also printing to screen, mixing the business logic with the presentation, which is bad.

That said, first method shouldn't even return the value. A separate `getSpeed()` method should exist to return that value. `Accelerate` should only increment the speed.

Also the variable should be named `speed` in lowercase and the method whould be called `accelerate()` also in lowercase.

Comment: Agree with everything 100% except the final paragraph - naming conventions vary, and whilst I don't disagree with you, at least the OP was being consistent...

Comment: This is C#. Instead of `public int getSpeed() { return speed; }` you should have `public int Speed { get { return speed; } }`. Also starting a method name in uppercase is standard convention in .NET. You seem to be treating this as if this was Java.

Comment: Methods are written in camel-case in C#, that is almost universally recognized coding style (which is also recommended by Microsoft).

Comment: @MatějZábský No. The C# convention is `PascalCase`, not `camelCase` for methods.

Comment: @codesparkle PascalCase = CamelCase http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: *Although the first letter of a camel case compound word may or may not be capitalized, the term camel case generally implies __lowercase__ first letter.* [...] *Pascal case is a synonym for __upper__ camel case* (from the article you quoted)

Answer (score 1):

From a real basic programming perspective, in C# if you need a method to get, derive, produce, instantiate, or otherwise communicate something back to the caller you use a function with the appropriate return type.

If you need a method to just do something and you don't need anything from it, use a void.

---

## Too Long; Did Not Read Info:

Functions return control to the caller upon completion along with a value or reference to some kind of product; a void is a special case function that has no corresponding product...it is kind of the type equivalent of null.

Some languages specifically differentiate between functions (methods that return a value) and subroutines (methods that do not return a value). C based languages instead use "void" to differentiate between them.

In C# specifically, void is internally mapped to a struct with some strange compiler enforced behavior; you can't really use this type for anything useful but if you are doing reflection you might notice it and think "hrm?":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.void.aspx

Eric Lippert, until recently a principal developer on the C# compiler team, had some interesting things to say about void a few years ago; it might provide some insight for you:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905083355/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/29/the-void-is-invariant.aspx)

Note that you could simulate functions using voids, via out or ref parameter(s) but this would be needlessly verbose and I daresay inelegant; functions are much cleaner and easier to read and write.

Personally, when I use a void it is usually for a private or protected method or to follow a design pattern. I tend to favor functions for public methods; even if only to return true / false to allow a feedback loop for the caller(s) or to assist in unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

because in most applications you want to do something with the new speed, like finding the relative speed between 2 objects, the your code there is no way to get the new speed (unless you have a separate method for that

also if you wrote everything out to the console you'd have a ton of spam on it, take minecraft it runs at 20 "ticks" a second with up to a hundred different moving entities, having 2000 messages of speed or position per second in the log is utterly useless and writing this out will lag the game

for another point it is not the responsibility of the accelerate method to write things out to the console